# How to test a stream made from a series of callback invocations

Tags: dart

Given the following repository class:

```dart
class Repository {
Repository({required Client client}) : _client = client;

final Client _client;
final StreamController<bool> _controller =
      StreamController<bool>.broadcast();

Stream<bool> get isEnabled async* {
    try {
      await _client.registerListener(
        callback: (String key) async {
          await _client
              .getValue(
                key: key,
                defaultValue: false,
              )
              .then(_controller.add)
              .catchError((Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
                 _controller.add(false);
              });
        },
      );
    } catch (error, stackTrace) {
      _controller.add(false);
    }

    yield* _controller.stream;
  }
}
```

I'm attempting to write a test that validates that the client methods are invoked.  I structured this implementation around a suggestion I saw in [How can I yield a value from a callback function inside my stream in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56914571/how-can-i-yield-a-value-from-a-callback-function-inside-my-stream-in-dart).

As for testing it, I needed to ensure that the callback could be invoked in order to see values emitted from the stream. This answer [How do I stub callbacks of a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67293043/how-do-i-stub-callbacks-of-a-method) helped me understand how to capture the callback so it could be invoked in the test. So my test looks like:

```dart
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

class _MockClient extends Mock implements Client {}

void main() {
  group('Repository', () {
    late Client client;
    late Repository repository;
    
    setUp(() {
      client = _MockClient();
      repository = Repository(client: client);
    });

    group('isEnabled', () {
      const value = true;

      setUp(() {
        when(
          () => client.getValue(
            key: any(named: 'key'),
            defaultValue: any(named: 'defaultValue'),
          ),
        ).thenAnswer((_) => Future.value(value));

        when(
          () => client.registerListener(
            callback: any(named: 'callback'),
          ),
        ).thenAnswer((_) => Future.value());
      });

      test(
        'calls client.registerListener with the callback',
        () async {
          await expectLater(
            repository.isEnabled,
            emitsInOrder([true]),
          );

          final captured = verify(
            () => client.registerListener(
              callback: captureAny(named: 'callback'),
            ),
          ).captured.single;

          final callback = captured as void Function(String);
          callback('key');

          verify(
            () => client.getValue(
              key: key,
              defaultValue: false,
            ),
          ).called(1);
        },
      );
    });
  });
}
```

When I run the test, it hangs like it is waiting for the stream to emit a value and I'm unsure of how to debug where it is going wrong.  I have written other tests for other similar classes that expose streams using the

```dart
await expectLater(
  repository.streamName,
  emitsInOrder([...]),
);
```

method and it has allowed me to perform similar verifications, but I have not had to deal with the added complexity of turning a client interface based on callbacks (that I don't control) into a stream of potential values.